# All 404 pages produce the error "Exception #0 (LogicException): Front controller reached 100 router match iterations"

Tags: magento2.4

We have the issue where every url that should return the 404 page, caused the following error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Exception #0 (LogicException): Front controller reached 100 router match iterations
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#2 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#3 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#4 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:71]
#5 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:23]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be that a value in `core_config_data` table with path `web/default/no_route` had the value `home.html`.
I have no idea where this came from.
However if you are on a test environment you should be good to delete this value (`delete from core_config_data where path = 'web/default/no_route';`) and flush cache. Then test if this also resolves for you.
**N.B** the default value is `cms` which is what is used when this row does not exist in the DB